# Delete certain text in a cell based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

[image]

I need your support to get the result in column B, it is basically see if there is 5 digits between a comma and a dash sign ( , & - ) in A cells and delete the text from , to -, the rest of the text need to be same without any changes as shown in the picture. I am looking for a normal excel equation not a vba code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your example, most of the substrings you are retaining do not have 5 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regrettably Substitute Doesn't Allow Wild Characters

Using `SEARCH` and `REPLACE` the only thing I could come up with was the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????-, ",A1)),REPLACE(A1,SEARCH("????-, ",A1),7,""),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", ????-",RIGHT(A1,7))),REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-6,7,""),A1))
```

which is removing only the first occurrence of the strings you want removed.

As a consolation I'm offering a simple VBA solution, which by **default** removes all `5-character` sub strings in a `", "-delimited` string.

In VBA (CTRL-F11) insert a new module into the workbook where you need it. In the code sheet of the module (probably Module1) copy/paste the following code:

```
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:    From a delimited string, removes all sub strings containing
'             a specified number of characters and returns the remainder
'             of the string.
' Returns:    A string, if there are any substrings with a different number
'             of characters than the specified number of characters,
'             or "", if not.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function FilterC(SourceValue As Variant, _
  Optional NumberOfCharacters As Long = 5, _
  Optional Delimiter As String = ", ") As String

    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Array Elements Counter
    Dim iTA As Long       ' Target Array Elements Counter
    Dim strC As String    ' Current String

    ' Check if SourceValue is text.
    If VarType(SourceValue) <> vbString Then Exit Function
    ' Check if SourceValue is "". For a cell in Excel this refers to an empty
    ' cell or a cell with a formula evaluating to "".
    If SourceValue = "" Then Exit Function

    ' Initialize Target Array Elements Counter.
    iTA = -1
    ' Write SourceValue to elements of Source Array (using 'Split').
    vntS = Split(SourceValue, Delimiter)

    ' Loop through elements of Source Array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(vntS)
        ' Write current element in Source Array to Current String.
        strC = vntS(i)
        ' Check if the length of Current String is NOT equal
        ' to NumberOfCharacters.
        If Len(strC) <> 5 Then GoSub TargetArray
    Next

    ' If only 'NumberOfCharacters' character strings are found.
    If iTA = -1 Then Exit Function

    ' Write elements of Target Array to FilterC (using "Join").
    FilterC = Join(vntT, Delimiter)

Exit Function

' Write String to Target Array.
TargetArray:
    ' Increase Target Array Elements Counter.
    iTA = iTA + 1
    ' Check if Target Array Elements Counter is greater than 0 i.e. if
    ' there already are any elements in Target Array.
    If iTA > 0 Then
        ' All, except the first element.
        ReDim Preserve vntT(iTA)
    Else
        ' Only the first element.
        ReDim vntT(0)
    End If
    ' Write Current String to Target Array.
    vntT(iTA) = strC
    ' Note: Target Array Elements Counter (iTA) was initalized with -1, so when
    ' the first time the code redirects to TargetArray (Subroutine),
    ' iTA will be 0 and only this time run through the Else clause
    ' and finally write Current String to Target Array.
Return

End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

In Excel for a result from `A1` use the following formula:

```
=FilterC(A1)
```

which is the short, **default** behavior of the fully qualified formula:

```
=FilterC(A1,5,", ")
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! this works exactly how I need it to be. Appreciate your time and support, really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your **screenshot** and not what you wrote, you seem to want to retain substrings that are in the format of `aaaa-nnnn` where `nnnnn` represents four or more digits. If you have the `FILTERXML` and `TEXTJOIN` functions, you can use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",",-"),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[number(.)<-999] /preceding::*[1] | //s[number(.)<-999]")),",-","-")
```

- Create an XML splitting on the commas and also the hyphen (but retain the hyphen)
- Construct an xPath which selects both the node preceding a numeric node with a value of less than `-999` and that numeric node itself.

  - The **negative** number comes from retaining the hyphen
- Put the values back together using `TEXTJOIN` with a comma separator

  - Remove the comma that is now preceding the hyphen.

[image]

If your version of Excel does not have those functions, VBA or possibly Power Query would be a better solution.

If wind up preferring a VBA solution, I suggest looking for substrings that meet your apparent criteria of a hyphenated substring where the right half is a number > 999.  If necessary, checking the left side for being all capital letters could be easily added.

```
Option Explicit
Function getStr(S As String) As String
    Dim V, W
    Dim sTemp As String

V = Split(S, ",")
For Each W In V
    If Val(Split(W, "-")(1)) > 999 Then _
        sTemp = sTemp & "," & W
Next W

getStr = Mid(sTemp, 2)

End Function
```

Comment: The obvious solution would be the 'Substitute' function, but it doesn't accept wild characters. So applying the logic to find "????-, " anywhere and ', ????-' at the end of the string, I got this formula: '=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????-, ",A1)),REPLACE(A1,SEARCH("????-, ",A1),7,""),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", ????-",RIGHT(A1,7))),REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-6,7,""),A1))' which only calculates the first occurrence.
If it is not to hard, could you apply this logic to another 'xml' version?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Given the limitation of not checking for digits to the right of the hyphen, did you try entering your formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`?

Comment: It's all of the same. It removes just the first occurrence.

Comment: `FIND` and `SEARCH` will only return the **first** instance of `find_text` within a string.  You need to break it up into an array to have it return multiple matches.

Comment: the limitation of this excel equation that it calculated only the first value appear and ignore the rest, the below vba function coded by VBasic2008 works perfect! appreciate your support guys!

Comment: @Dawood As shown in the screenshot in my answer, the formula using `FILTERXML` and `TEXTJOIN` returns all of the values as per your example.